# Clustering By Interval Via Hash of Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, histogram

I have a data that looks like this

```
#Status value
TP       5.000
TP       3.000
TP       3.000
TN       10.000
TP       2.000
TP       9.000
TN       1.000
TP       9.000
TN       1.000
```

What we want to do is to cluster the Status based on the given interval in `value`.
Let that interval be `1-3, 4-6, 7-9, 10-12, etc ..` (i.e. Bin size 3).

We hope to get the hash of array like this:

```
my %hoa = (
'1-3' => [TP,TP,TP,TN,TN],
'4-6' => [TP],
'7-9' => [TP,TP],
'10-12' => [TN]);
```

What's the way to achieve that?

**Update**: Corrected the HoA for `7-9`, thanks to ysth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstracting away the code to determine interval:

```
sub interval {
    my ($val) = @_;
    my $i = int( ( $val + 2 ) / 3 );
    my $interval = sprintf( '%d-%d', $i * 3 -2, $i * 3 );
    return $interval;
}

my %hoa;
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    next if $line =~ /^#/;
    my ($status, $value) = split ' ', $line;
    push @{ $hoa{ interval($value) } }, $status;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hoa;
```

(which gets two TPs for 7-9, not one as you show).

Answer (score 2):

ysth's answer was the first thing that occurred to me as well, and I think he has the right approach.

I'd just like to leave a suggestion: you could use a clustering algorithm to do this for you in a future-proof kind of way (say, when your data becomes multidimensional). [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), for example, would work fine, even for 1D data such as yours.

For example:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Algorithm::KMeans;

my $datafile = $ARGV[0] or die;
my $K        = $ARGV[1] or 0;
my $mask     = 'N1';

my $clusterer = Algorithm::KMeans->new(
    datafile => $datafile,
    mask     => $mask,
    K        => $K,
    terminal_output => 0,
);

$clusterer->read_data_from_file();

my ($clusters, $cluster_centers) = $clusterer->kmeans();

my %clusters;

while (@$clusters) {

    my $cluster = shift @$clusters;
    my $center  = shift @$cluster_centers;

    $clusters{"@$center"} = $cluster;
}

use YAML; print Dump \%clusters;
```